# How can I print a list with jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to generate an HTML table with Jinja2. The data for the table is in an `collections.OrderedDict` where the keys are strings and the values are lists of strings.

I've tried to implement it using the following loops:

```
{% for key in table.keys() %}
  {% for a_list in table[key] %}
    {% for a_value in a_list %}
      {{ a_value }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Except in the Python console this works but in Jinja2 it dies with the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

How do I iterate through a list in Jinja2?

Answer (score 5):

You have one loop too many. `table[key]` is a list object, so looping over that gives you the values in the list:

```
{% for key in table.keys() %}
  {% for a_value in table[key] %}
    {{ a_value }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Your extraneous loop tried to loop over the integer objects in your lists. Note that you don't need to loop over the `keys()` result; you can loop directly over the dictionary:

```
{% for key in table %}
  {% for a_value in table[key] %}
    {{ a_value }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you are not using the key in the loop, just loop directly over the values:

```
{% for list_value in table.values() %}
  {% for a_value in list_value %}
    {{ a_value }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```